# Call a function within a function and include the original function's warning message?

Tags: r

I would like to call a low-level function within another function, and for the warning message of the original function to be clearly printed when the higher-order function is called.

I have written a low-level function that includes a warning message, like the one below:

```
square_x <- function(x) {
  
  if(x < 0) {
    
    warning("x < 0")
    
  }
  
  x^2
  
}
```

And then I wish to define another function that calls upon `square_x`.

```
use_square_x_on_vector <- function(vector) {
  
  map(vector, square_x)
  
}
```

The second function works as expected e.g.

```
use_square_x_on_vector(-1:1)
```

However, the warning message from the original function `square_x` does not state which function the warning relates to - it looks like this:

```
Warning message:
In .f(.x[[i]], ...) : x < 0
```

Is there a way to make the warning message state:

```
Warning message:
In square_x : x < 0
```

Comment: you say you are writing `square_x`, just add that text to your warning message with `call. = FALSE`

Comment: @rawr post as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  Please do post as answer @rawr.